# AppArmour question - why was it closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

This questions was recently closed:
[MySQL was stopped](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/210208/mysql-was-stopped/210218)

As you can see, the close notice says it's off-topic and too localized.

Does that mean all questions where the problem turns out to be related to AppArmour, SELinux or other security systems should also be closed?

I think security system configuration issues can actually be very relevant to DBAs. But maybe that's just me?

Answer (score 2):

It was [bumped to the home page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511) by the Community User as an old question with no answers at a positive score. The point of bumping is to reassess the quality of the question and its answers.

On balance, it looked *too localized* to me, had a very low number of views after 1 year and 8 months, no votes, and the author has never responded to your questions or even interacted with the site again - so I closed it.

> I think security system configuration issues can actually be very relevant to DBAs. But maybe that's just me?

*Some* security system configuration issues will be on topic, but that doesn't mean all are, and not all on-topic questions are suitable for the long-term.

That said, as a user with the [close and reopen privilege](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) you may vote to reopen it if you think it is on-topic and has lasting value to the site. That will start a reopen review process where other community members with that privilege can assess the merits of reopening.